# Duplicated SQL Server Execution Times For Dynamic Query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

[image]

I'm getting duplicated SQL Server Execution Times from SET STATISTICS IO,TIME ON with dynamic queries. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: You could put `SET STATISTICS` inside the dynamic batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an output for each statement. The query in `@sql` is one statement that gives you the first output and calling `exec` is a statement of its own and outputs duration for all the statements in `@sql`.

So if you have two statements in `@sql` you get three outputs.

```
exec (N'select * from dbo.YourTable; select * from dbo.YourTable;');
```

Output with set statistics time on:

```
(74 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 164 ms.

(74 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 144 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 309 ms.
```